# How to enhance the album-loading speed

Tags: ios, objective-c, photosframework

I am doing a project which needs to show the photos in the system album. I use a ViewController with a `UICollectionView` to show all photos get from the ViewModel. The ViewModel will get the photos in the `viewDidLoad` method.

But when there are more than a thousand photos in the album, the loading speed will be really slow. I do not want to set the `PHImageRequestOptions.synchronous` to `No` because it will make me get an unclear thumb image. How to solve this problem?

Here is the code:

```
- (void)enumerateAssetsInAssetCollection:(PHAssetCollection *)assetCollection original:(BOOL)original{
    NSLog(@"%@", assetCollection.localizedTitle);

    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc] init];

    options.synchronous = YES;
    options.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeExact;
    options.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
    options.normalizedCropRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, kSCREEN_WIDTH/3, kSCREEN_WIDTH/3);

    PHFetchResult<PHAsset *> *assets = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:assetCollection options:nil];
    for (PHAsset *asset in assets) {
         CGSize size = original ? CGSizeMake(asset.pixelWidth, asset.pixelHeight) : CGSizeMake(kSCREEN_WIDTH/3, kSCREEN_WIDTH/3);

         [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFill options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable result, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
            NSLog(@"%@", result);
            [self.photoArray addObject:result];
         }];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show them all at once. So the idea of fetching them all at once up front is silly.  Use the PHCachingImageManager... This situation is exactly what it's for!

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHCachingImageManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/PHCachingImageManager